# Converting csv to json file format . not sure how to achieve the expected output in json using pandas or python

Tags: python, json, pandas

How to convert flat file to json format using pandas or python. I have tried below code to read csv file and explicitly creating address column.

**Code Tried**

```
df = pd.read_csv(input_file, sep=",", header=0)
    df['address'] = df.apply(
        lambda x: dict(line1=x['line1'], line2=x['line2'], line3=x['line3']), axis=1)
    print(df)
```

**Input Data file**

```
id,name,line1,line2,line3
5,"ABC","123","456",67
5,"ABC","456","456",67
```

**Output Getting in json format**

```
[
    {
    "source_id":5,
    "name":"ABC",
    "line1":123,
    "line2":456,
    "line3":67,
    "address":{
            "line1":123,
            "line2":456,
            "line3":67
            }
    },
    {
    "source_id":5,
    "name":"ABC",
    "line1":456,
    "line2":456,
    "line3":67
    "address":{
            "line1":456,
            "line2":456,
            "line3":67
            }
    }
]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[
    {
        "source_id": 5,
        "name":"ABC",
        "address":[
                {
                "line1": 123,
                "line2": 456,
                "line3": 67
                },
                {
                "line1": 456,
                "line2": 456,
                "line3": 67
                }
            ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
df=df.rename(columns={'id':'source_id'})
g_cols=['source_id','fn','ln','email','dob']
cols=df.columns[~df.columns.isin(g_cols)]
out=(df.groupby(g_cols)[cols]
       .apply(lambda x:x.to_dict('records'))
       .reset_index(name='address').to_dict('records'))
```

output of `out`:

```
[{'source_id': 5,
  'fn': 'sam',
  'ln': 'joe',
  'email': 'sam123@gmail.com',
  'dob': '05-12-1984',
  'address': [{'ln1': 123,
    'ln2': 456,
    'ln3': 67,
    'cty': 'xxx',
    'state': 'tn',
    'cntry': 'india'},
   {'ln1': 456,
    'ln2': 456,
    'ln3': 67,
    'cty': 'xxx',
    'state': 'tn',
    'cntry': 'india'},
   {'ln1': 123,
    'ln2': 789,
    'ln3': 67,
    'cty': 'xxx',
    'state': 'tn',
    'cntry': 'india'}]},
 {'source_id': 7,
  'fn': 'priya',
  'ln': 'kannan',
  'email': 'shanthapriya794@gmail.com',
  'dob': '07-12-1994',
  'address': [{'ln1': 123,
    'ln2': 456,
    'ln3': 67,
    'cty': 'mdu',
    'state': 'tn',
    'cntry': 'india'}]}]
```

Comment: Thanku so much man.. I have edit data set little bit.. I have added name columns that will change our code little bit here and there. can you have suggest me for that.

Comment: @Naveen updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: I think we can't use filter here. I have some other columns(city,state and country) as well. Stackoverflow was not allowing me to put full data. that's why i put partial input only.

Comment: @Naveen so how you want to show the data of other columns?

Comment: "address":{"line1":123,"line2":456,"line3":67,"city":"xxx","state":"tn","country":"india"}

Comment: @Naveen updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235780/discussion-between-naveen-and-anurag-dabas).

Comment: We have 2 rows with same email. We need to convert those email into multivalue. For example : {
'source_id': 7,
'fname': 'priya',
'lname': 'kannan',
'email': ['shanthapriya794@gmail.com','shanthapriya7964@gmail.com']
'date_of_birth': '07-12-1994',
'address': [{
'line1': 123,
'line2': 456,
'line3': 67,
'city': 'mdu',
'state': 'tn',
'country': 'india'
}]
},

Comment: @Naveen it seems to be a different question but anyway in that case use `groupby()` and aggregrate `list`

Comment: I have tried to using groupby and aggregate list but no luck.

Comment: I have tried this ...
 cols= df.columns[~df.columns.isin(g_cols)]
    df1 = (df.groupby(g_cols)[cols]
           .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('records'))
           .reset_index(name='address').to_dict('records'))

    df3 = pd.DataFrame(df1)

    df2 = df.groupby('source_id', as_index=False)[g_cols].agg(lambda x: set(x)).to_dict('records')
    df4 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
    frames = [df2, df3]
    result = pd.merge(df3, df4, on='source_id')

Answer (score 0):

```
path = config['path']['input_file_path']
json_path = config['json_path']['input_json_path']
g_cols = ['source_id', 'fname', 'lname', 'email', 'date_of_birth']
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=",", header=0)
with open(json_path, 'r') as f:
    dict_val = json.load(f)
df.columns = df.columns.to_series().map(dict_val)
cols= df.columns[~df.columns.isin(g_cols)]
g_cols.remove('email')
df1 = (df.sort_values(g_cols).set_index(g_cols).assign(email=df.groupby(g_cols)['email'].agg(lambda x: tuple(pd.unique(x)))).reset_index())
g_cols.append('email')
df2 = df1.groupby(g_cols)[cols].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('records')).reset_index(name='address').to_dict('record')
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
```